# how do I read a text file into my .py file with Flask and then get a line-by-line array?

Tags: flask

Please see here for my command line output: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Qbl.jpg)

It says the file /static/poemInput.txt doesn't exist.. but as you can see, it clearly exists when I execute `ls static`. Is there a problem with how I'm naming the files?

context:
I'm very new to flask but I have a python app that I want to deploy online. I am just trying to import the text file I use in the app, however it isn't found.

I know the text file should be in the static folder, and I used open_url as required.

I was getting the errors specified [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/flask/flask-url-for/) so my `with open` block is inside a `with.app.test_request_context():` block.

**EDIT**
I tried what was suggested by Luan Nguyen and used the `app.open_resource()` function, but then I get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)`. This was fixed in python's open function (as in my original code) by setting encoding to latin1... how can I do this with flask's open_resource function?? I tried doing `f.encode('latin1')` but I got error: `_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Essentially: how do I read a text file into my .py file with Flask and then get a line-by-line array?

Comment: Just for the starter, the error says `/static/poemInput.txt` doesn't exist while you are listing `~/Downloads/poem/static` directory...

Comment: please see my edits! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**

The problem is with your `open` call. `url_for` returned this string `'/static/poemInput.txt'`. When you put this string directly into Python's `open`, it will find the file *at* `<system_root>/static/poemInput.txt`, and not *at* `<your_project_directory>/static/poemInput.txt`.

**Solution**

Given you might have a running Flask instance, you should be using Flask's [`open_resource`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource) function. With this structure:

```
/myapplication.py
/schema.sql
/static
    /poemInput.txt
    /style.css
/templates
    /layout.html
    /index.html
```

You could do something like:

```
with app.open_resource('static/poemInput.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    do_something_with(contents)
```

Comment: I tried this, but now I get a "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)". This was fixed in python's open function by setting encoding to latin1... how can I do this with flask's open_resource function?? I tried doing f.encode('latin1') but I got error: "_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Comment: @user699290 You should be able to just change `contents = f.read()` to `contents = f.read().decode('latin1')`.